# WSO2 APIM Store API Redirecting to Login Page

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are in the process of migrating from WSO2 APIM 2.6 to 4.2.  We are doing this by installing a new 4.2 on a new VM and migrating over.  Both the old and new servers are fully scripted installations (ansible) so the same for all our instances.

We have a script which uses the Store APIs to extract a list of applications and subscriptions from the old server.  We then use the WSO2 CLI to import them to the new one.

This is working everywhere except one server.  The script to extract the applications on the old server fails.  The relevant steps are

1. First we call `/client-registration/v0.14/register` with our admin user's username and password as the Basic auth to get a client
2. Then we call `/token` with Basic auth being built up using the `clientId` and `clientSecret` from that response.  The body has `grant_type=password` and the username and password for our subscribing user and `scope=apim:subscribe`.  This returns a token
3. We then call `/api/am/store/v0.14/applications?limit=1000` with the authorisation being the Bearer token from step 2

This is the same script running everywhere.  On all other machines this works and returns a list of Applications.  But on one machine this consistently return a 302 redirect with a `Location` header in the response redirecting to `/carbon/admin/login.jsp`  (We ran it manually with extra verbosity to see where it redirected, but the script shows 302)

There are no entries at all in either wso2carbon.log or wso2-apigw-errors.log for these calls.  I do see an entry (slightly delayed, but it comes) in http_access_2023-09-01.log so it is coming to the right instance.

What could be the issue?  Permissions seem the same between environments.  Can the Store API be missing somehow?  Any hints where to look gratefully received - I'm a bit out of ideas.

Comment: Is the url you invoke correct? Redirection to carbon usually happens when an unknown url is called.

Comment: Yes.  I've double-checked.  Also, it's a script that fails and it works on every other environment